# How to view all login history in MacOS High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, login, logs

How can I log all login history until now? By "all" I mean all users: admin, guests, and every other user.

I am using MacOS HighSierra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **Terminal**, use the `last` *command*.

Also, read the manual page for `last`, in **Terminal**: `man last`

Comment: Is there something that has changed from 10.11 (El Capitan) to 10.13 (High Sierra)? I'm asking because if I type ```last``` in the terminal on El Capitan, the only output I get is ```wtmp begins Mon Oct 25 16:40```, or 5 mins later ```wtmp begins Mon Oct 25 16:45```. The man page says: "If no users, hostnames or terminals are specified, last prints a record of all logins and logouts."

Comment: @Alex Ixeras, I just booted an **OS X 10.11.6** system and the `last` _command_ is working as stated in its _manual page_ and shows my current _login_ and other previous ones along with _reboot_ and _shutdown_ times.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know why my output is so different? Is there any setting I’m missing?

Comment: @Alex Ixeras, If you are having an issue, then I'd suggest you post a question.

Answer (score 4):

Checked on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5

```
sudo log show --style syslog  --last 30m | awk '/Enter/ && /unlockUIBecomesActive/ {print $1 " " $2}'
```

The above no longer works in macOS Sonoma, but this seems to:

```
sudo log show --style syslog  --last 1d | awk '/CA sending unlock success to dispatch/ {print $1 " " $2}'
```

Comment: This command only catches GUI logins. It is OK if the user does not have [does not use] SSH logins on MacOS. Else it must use `last` which catches both.

Comment: I like log answers, +1. Is there any way to replace awk with log's `--predicate`, something like `--predicate 'eventMessage contains …'`?

Comment: The `last` command is the accepted answer and provides user names. In addition to the issues @Prado mentioned, this solution doesn't show the user name. I doubt the poster was looking for just a list of times when logins occurred with no reference to the username.

Comment: @grg since you like logs, check my other answer here about using it https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367784/341083 . About this thread, `last` is a specific command from UNIX/BSD just for that purpose, we can trust its results, logger can be rewritten and it not reliable for such thing, unless previously configured for longer data storage. I prefer `last` also for this reason.

Comment: @Prado last doesn't catch logins which happens after screen saver

Comment: because you are already logged-in, that is not a login, is just a unlock screen feature. But I understand now what you are telling, you want both things, login+unlock screen. That's interesting for several situations on the view of user control.

Comment: @Prado so maybe we need to combine last and log and coalece by time?

Comment: Can you guys please tell me what's the event to check when the user has locked the computer and how to combine that with awk so I can have something like "locked: 15:21:17" and "unlocked: 15:31:00"? I just want to find out how long I spend on lunch :)

Answer (score 0):

log show --style syslog  --last 30m --predicate 'eventMessage CONTAINS "unlockUIBecomesActive"' --info

Can also use

log show --style syslog  --start "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" --end "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" --predicate 'eventMessage CONTAINS "unlockUIBecomesActive"' --info

etc.