# Make a login/logout script in mac

Tags: mac, command-line, bash, launchd

What would be the best way to log login, logout and the user that is logging into the mac? I have some machines which I control from remote desktop. I want to monitor who is logging into them and what time they are logging out and the user as well. I tried with last but the BSD one is different from the Linux (GNU) one and not that versatile. I need the log weekly so I can run a cronjob to send me the logs of every machine.

My current approach:

Make a script to log the activity
Copy the script into each machine(37 machines) :(
Then run another cronjob to send the logs into my machines using scp.
Am I doing this right ?

This is what I did:

I have a shell script which I want to run at login as well as logout.

It's something like this

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Define the log file path
LOG_FILE="/Users/kamabokogonpachiro/Desktop/logfile.log"

# Function to log login
log_login() {
    echo "$(date) - User $1 logged in" >> "$LOG_FILE"
}

# Function to log logout
log_logout() {
    echo "$(date) - User $1 logged out" >> "$LOG_FILE"
}

# Check if the script is called with a username argument
if [ "$1" ]; then
    # If the script is called with "logout" as the first argument, log the logout
    if [ "$1" = "logout" ]; then
        log_logout "$2"
    else
        # Otherwise, log the login
        log_login "$1"
    fi
fi
```

The login script is saved at `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.login.plist` and the contents are

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.login.sh</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/Users/kamabokogonpachiro/Desktop/logfile.sh</string>
        <string>login</string>
        <string>$(whoami)</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/kamabokogonpachiro/Desktop</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Similarly the logout script is located at `~/Library/LogoutAgents/com.user.logout.plist` and the contents are

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.logout</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/kamabokogonpachiro/Desktop/logfile.sh</string>
        <string>logout</string>
        <string>username</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I did `launchctl load ...` as well.

Still, they are not working the shell script is marked as executable as well. I don't know what am I missing. Is my approach incorrect? Are there any better ways? I tried with `last` but the BSD one is different from the `Linux (GNU)` one and not that versatile.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77592492/make-a-login-logout-script-in-mac for the original version of this question. You already got some feedback there, is there a specific reason you didn't integrate that into your solution yet (because the scripts above will for sure not work)? Also, start small, e.g. create a simple LaunchAgent daemon which just touches a file, and extend once you get it to work. RIght now, there are too many things which can and do go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## `utmpx` – user accounting database

If the `last` and `log` methods in the [duplicate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308525/how-to-view-all-login-history-in-macos-high-sierra) are not enough, consider copying each client's `/var/run/utmpx` file and examine its contents on your local computer.

This should be a more reliable approach than launchd jobs and custom log files.